# Heroku messes up styles

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I uploaded my app to heroku and suddenly everything is just changed, text is randomly aligned left and right while in my own server it's all in the middle just like I say'd it to.

What is going on with it?

Link to page so you can see whats going on: https://harjutus2.herokuapp.com

Edit: I have it aligned middle in css files and also in every p b and h2 element out of frustration to get it work. Plus my links are supposed to be colored blue but that's suddenly gone also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your styles look good to me!

---

**Assets**

There's something you should know about [Heroku's handling of styles](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline). You have to `precompile` your assets before you deploy the app. Reason for this is to give the app a consistent feel, and reduces load on the Heroku dynos

Here's how to set it up:

```
#config/environments/production.rb
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = true
```

When you want to deploy to Heroku, you just need to run:

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

This will precompile your styles, allowing you to keep them consistent on Heroku & locally