# React App On Heroku - CSS Styling Not Taking Effect On Mobile Devices

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, typescript, heroku

**The Problem**

I have a React app that is deployed to Heroku that uses `create-react-app` to do all of the bundling in the background.

I am using a Node.js backend written in Typescript running node version `10.15.3`

When I serve my site locally in development everything goes fine. I run `npm start` and the website serves correctly and looks like this:

[image: Site In Development & Production On My Laptop]

The site also looks the same on staging & production.

But when I look at the site on my mobile device I see:

[image]

I have reached out to Heroku support and they told me that they didn't know what was going on.

It seems that all problems with this online are solved for people using Ruby & I haven't seen a single person using React run into this.

All the right files exist in the build folder.

Also, here is my `index.js`:

```
import LoadingIndicator from './components/elements/LoadingIndicator';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { StripeProvider } from 'react-stripe-elements';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import * as Environment from './Environment';
import App from './components/App';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import './index.css';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import middleware from './middleware';
import rootReducer from './reducers';
import { createStore } from 'redux';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'app',
  storage
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const store = createStore(persistedReducer, middleware);
const persistor = persistStore(store);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={<LoadingIndicator />} persistor={persistor}>
      <StripeProvider apiKey={Environment.get("STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY")}>
        <Router>
          <App />
        </Router>
      </StripeProvider>
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And my folder structure:

[image: Folder Structure]

**Resources I Have Referenced:**

- [Create React App Deployment](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment)
- [Creating A Production Build](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/production-build)
- [Create React App Deployment (Heroku Section)](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#heroku-https-wwwherokucom)
- [Checking The Heroku App's File System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38924458/how-to-see-files-and-file-structure-on-a-deployed-heroku-app)
- [CSS Is Looking Different On Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056684/css-is-looking-different-on-heroku)
- [Heroku Messes Up Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21198094/heroku-messes-up-styles)

Comment: Can you show an example as to how you're importing the styles to the app. You have mentioned "But when I look at the site on my mobile device I see" and included the image. How is it actually supposed to look like. Include that image as well.

Comment: @Muljayan updated

Comment: So your issue is that the O, omega and theta icons don't appear on mobile when you host it on heroku is it ?

Comment: @Muljayan That is normal, it is the fonts that are messed up. As well as scroll behavior. Scrolling is “sticky” on mobile vs desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">` to the `<head>` section in my `index.html` file.

Not sure how it loaded locally...probably because I have the font on my laptop? Not sure but that made it work.

It was not anything to do with CSS not loading or being served.